# How can we draw Circle progress as "three fourths" - 3/4?

Tags: ios, objective-c, calayer, uibezierpath, cashapelayer

Currently am working on a circular chart,There is no issue on drawing full circle. I also need to draw a 3/4 circle, Is there any specify math to define 3/4 circle path. I tried by reducing missed position values with full circle but cant get accurate result. Could anyone help with this? If any need I

```
UIBezierPath *circlePath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2.0f, self.frame.size.height/2.0f)
                                                              radius:(self.frame.size.height * 0.5) - ([_lineWidth floatValue]/2.0f)
                                                          startAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(startAngle)
                                                            endAngle:DEGREES_TO_RADIANS(endAngle)
                                                           clockwise:clockwise];

    circle               = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    circle.path          = circlePath.CGPath;
    circle.lineCap       = kCALineCapRound;
    circle.fillColor     = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;
    circle.lineWidth     = [_lineWidth floatValue];
    circle.zPosition     = 1; [self.layer addSublayer:circle];
;
```

Please refer image below,

[image: 3/4 Circle]

**Note:** I have attached the sample image from web but am sure i need the same results.

Answer (score 2):

You already have the code that you need. The function `bezierPathWithArcCenter:radius:startAngle:endAngle:clockwise:` takes a start angle and an end angle. If you pass in a start angle of 0 and an end angle of 3π/2 you'll get a 3/4 circle. (3π/2 is 270 degrees, or 3/4 of a full circle.)

Note that if your goal is to animate a circle from 0 to 360 degrees then you need to use a different technique. For that you want to create a path of the full circle, install that into a CAShapeLayer, then animate the layer's strokeEnd property from 0 to 1.